# jsPdf Android Stock browser error

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, browser, cross-browser

I'm developing a script that transforms a HTML table in pdf document. To do this i use jsPdf and jsPDF-AutoTable. I did some testing on various brwser and everything works fine except for the Android Stock Browser.

Android stock browser error :

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf:
>   "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJ…l6ZSAxOQovUm9vdCAxOCAwIFIKL0luZm8gMTcgMCBSCj4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgozMDk5CiUlRU9G".

**jsPdf Code**
Error jspdf.debug.js line 863

> case 'dataurl':   return global.document.location.href = datauri;

jspdf version: jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The "Android stock browser error" is probably just a warning that you most likely don't have to worry about. However it might be that old versions of the android stock browser don't support datauri as location href. I would try to use the save method instead to get the pdf.

```
doc.save('table.pdf');
```